# Thread 1: signal sigabrt error

Tags: objective-c

Why do I get the thread error on the `NSLog(@"%@", numbers[i]);` line?

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

@autoreleasepool {

    NSMutableArray *numbers = [NSMutableArray array];
    int i;

    //Create an arry with the number 0-9

    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        numbers[i] = @(i);

        //Sequence through the array and display the values

        for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
            NSLog(@"%@", numbers[i]);

            //Look how NSLog can display it with a singe %@ format

            NSLog(@"====== Using a single NSLog");
            NSLog(@"%@", numbers);
        }
    }

}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: This certainly is not an Xcode question.

Comment: Also, you could **read** the (entire) exception message -- the problem is that you are accessing the array out of bounds.

Comment: If you forgive the observation, while I'm glad you got an answer to your question, but, in the future, if you post a question regarding an error or crash, make sure to post the full error message and the stack trace. See [My App Crashed, Now What?](http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're receiving an exception because you have your two `for` loops nested, and the inner one is trying to iterate through ten values in `numbers` array, but trying to do that before you've done populating the array in the outer loop.

I presume you do not want those `for` loops nested:

```
NSMutableArray *numbers = [NSMutableArray array];
int i;

//Create an array with the number 0-9

for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    numbers[i] = @(i);

//Sequence through the array and display the values

for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) 
    NSLog(@"%@", numbers[i]);

//Look how NSLog can display it with a single %@ format

NSLog(@"====== Using a single NSLog");
NSLog(@"%@", numbers);
```